# Twilio API issue

Tags: java, eclipse, twilio

Hello stackoverflow,

This might be a really easy question but I am having issues with building a basic sms reply application in java. I googled around and couldn't find a solution for my problem. The issue occurs when I do the following imports:

```
import com.twilio.sdk.verbs.TwiMLResponse;
import com.twilio.sdk.verbs.TwiMLException;
import com.twilio.sdk.verbs.Message;
```

Eclipse throws an error when I try calling and implementing the Message class saying`The import com.twilio.sdk.verbs.Message cannot be resolved` . I have no issues with the other classes, just the Message class. And I have used Maven to compile the project.

Anybody have any solutions and/or solutions for this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using the wrong Twilio SDK version in my maven dependency. I was using 3.3.15 and I updated it to 4.4.2 and it solved my issue. Thanks for all the comments and replies

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify external libraries in the Build Path.

In Eclipse right click on *your project > Build Path > Configure Build Path > Libraries > Add JARs* (or "Add External JARs" if you didn't copy it into your project folder).

If it still doesn't work there might be dependencies you are missing, so you need those as well. To save the headache you could also use [Maven](http://www.eclipse.org/m2e/) to download them [automatically](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.twilio.sdk/twilio-java-sdk/4.4.1).

Comment: I used maven to compile it

Comment: Provide that in your question next time. You should check your build path libraries anyway.